# How to hide menu until after a user starts scrolling in WordPress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

The purpose of this code is to hide the menu until a user starts scrolling and only do so for devices with viewports above 1000px. I'm doing this in WordPress.

At the moment I have to click the scroll bar and move a little for the menu to disappear which should not be the case. I need the menu to be hidden even without any action so that it now appears once the user begins scrolling.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var y = $(window).scrollTop();
    var width = $(window).innerWidth();

    if (window.location.pathname == '/') {
      if (window.innerWidth > 1000) {
        if (y > 0) {
          $('#top').fadeIn();
          $('#header-space').fadeIn();
        } else {
          $('#top').fadeOut();
          $('#header-space').fadeOut();
        }
      }
    } else {}
  });
});
```

Comment: If your code used to work but no longer does check the console for errors to debug

Comment: The code is still working but the behavior changed. There are no errors.

Comment: Hopefully someone can help. I have given this all I got as a beginner.

Comment: Are you sure that you are passing all the if checks, e.g. if the pathname really is `/` and that the viewport width is indeed >1000px? Otherwise you will need to create an MCVE to show us exactly what the issue is.

Comment: I think the code is firing on scroll. Meaning it's basically waiting for the user to begin scrolling. Not sure how to go about this.

Comment: I was missing this css style. So this now works after adding this. Thanks all. `#top, #header-space {
 position:relative;
  display:none
}`